# Problem on continuous probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Problem:We  pick two random numbers, x and y, between 0 and 2. What is the probability that x*y<1 AND y/x<1.
I am familiar with continuous probability distributions for one variable, but it seems to me that I have to handle two variables, and I have no idea how. Any help would be appreciated
Apostolos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let random variables $X$ and $Y$ be the numbers picked. We will need to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**.

Draw the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,2)$, and $(0,2)$. Our joint density function is $\frac{1}{4}$ in this square and $0$ elsewhere.

Draw the line $y=x$ and the part of the hyperbola $xy=1$ that lies in the first quadrant.

Shade in the part of the square that is below $y=x$ and below the hyperbola. Our answer is the area of this shaded region $D$, times $\frac{1}{4}$. Another way of putting it is that our probability is 
$$\iint_D \frac{1}{4}\,dy\,dx.$$

We use the area approach. To find the area, note that $y=x$ and $xy=1$ meet at $(1,1)$. So the area of $D$ is
$$\int_0^1 x\,dx+\int_1^2\frac{dx}{x}.$$
Integrate. We get $\frac{1}{2}+\ln 2$. for the probability, divide by $4$.

Comment: The area approach is clearer to me, but I don't get why I should divide by four to get the probability.

Comment: The individual density functions are $\frac{1}{2}$ on the interval $(0,2)$, so the joint density function is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ on the square. Or to put it another way, the whole square has area $4$, and the joint distribution is uniform on the square, so the probability of landing in any particular region of the square with area $A$ is the ratio of $A$ to the area of the whole square, that is, $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: I'm guessing that the distribution is 1/(b-a). Ok, I am grateful for your help!!!!

Comment: Sure, if $W$ is uniformly distributed on $(a,b)$, then the density function of $W$ is $\frac{1}{b-a}$ on the interval.

Comment: Right! Thanks again for clarifying the concept!

Comment: You are welcome.